# vue3 if condition with v-for loop

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

i am getting all data from my database to view using vue3 and laravel.

right now it's working fine, but i want to apply if condition with v-for.

for example: show todo only if (progress=1).

**vue:** this part is working fine to get everything from database

```
import axios from "axios";
import { defineComponent, reactive } from 'vue'



    export default defineComponent({
      setup() {
    
        const state=reactive({
          todos:[],
          todoText:"",
        });
    function getTodos(){  
       axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos')
       .then(response=>{
         state.todos=response.data;
       });
     } 
     getTodos();
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div v-for="(todo,index) in state.todos" :key="index" class="   border-dashed bg-white  rounded-md shadow-md  ">
    <div class="justify-between flex ">
    <div  class="text-gray-600 p-4 font-medium "> {{todo.text}}
    <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm"> Small Details </span> 
    <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm"> Progress: {{todo.progress}} </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**result:** i don't want to show todo if progress=0, currently it is showing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template tag if you do not want to have a DOM element added to your code:

```html
<div v-for="(todo,index) in state.todos" :key="index" class="border-dashed bg-white rounded-md shadow-md">
  <template v-if="todo.progress !== 0">
    <div class="justify-between flex" />
    <div class="text-gray-600 p-4 font-medium">{{todo.text}}
      <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm"> Small Details </span> 
      <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm"> Progress: {{todo.progress}} </span> 
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Side note: you should check your closing tags, they aren't coherent in your current question.

Comment: is it correct way to do it, or i should do it in laravel controller, or is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: You can also add a `v-if` on your DIV elements; anywhere inside the scope of your `v-for` loop. To the question if you should do it in Laravel; it depends. Usually the back-end should decide what the front has to display, but maybe you need these todos for something else. I can't answer that question without more information.

Comment: Thankyou , i appreciate your help, todo.progress is boolean, if i want to check equal to I'll have to use same as you did, todo.progress==0 to check if its equal to?

Comment: If it's a boolean, just use `v-if="todo.progress"` without any boolean operation. or `!todo.progress` if you want to display the false ones.

Comment: Thankyou, i am new to vue, where can i learn such to the point information about vue dev, any references to learn from?

Comment: The official documentation would be a great start, to begin with: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ for version 2; or https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html for version 3.